# Android: adb pull command not working/not able to perform

Tags: android, command, adb, pull

I am trying to copy a complete directory on my device(`not rooted`) to a directory in my mac say `/Users/myUserName/Documents/Copied` using the android [Pull commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles) but every time I run the command, it gives me a message saying `remote object does not exist`.

I used

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/PB/").getAbsolutePath();`

to get the absolute path of the directory in my device which comes out to be `/storage/emulated/0/PB` . Now I run the below command

```
./adb pull /storage/emulated/0/PB /Users/myUserName/Documents/Copied/
```

and I get following response

```
remote object '/storage/emulated/0/PB' does not exist
```

I don't know whats wrong with my approach and why is this not working even if the directory is there in my device.

Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `adb pull /sdcard/PB`.

Comment: great. This actually worked. I earlier tried `/sdcard/0/PB` so had to figure out another way of getting absolute path. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the cell, the path maybe:

```
/storage/emulated/0/miad/cache/3287521801
```

and you should convert the path to

```
/sdcard/miad/cache/3287521801
```

when invoking`adb pull`:

```
adb pull /sdcard/miad/cache/3287521801
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which got resolved, and this is what I found.
1) The file/folder names are case-sensitive. IF I use the wrong case, it returns the same error.
2) I had to find the correct path. I used the following command to locate the folder 'Backups'.

```
adb shell find / -type d -iname backups
```

`-type d` is to specify 'directory'
and -iname is to specify a case insensitive name search.

So, I got a list of folder paths where I also got the case of the folders. I found it was all-caps.

I then did `adb pull /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS` and it worked perfectly rightaway.